# Sequelize 2.0 Postgres connection manager error

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize with Postgres and recently updated Sequelize.js to 2.0.0-rc1.

The  psql connection manager seems to break suddenly after every server start with the following error:

```
Cannot call method 'on' of undefined
```

which is traced down to:

```
at Promise.<anonymous> (/Volumes/Work/projects/boon/server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:90:10)
```

Are there any known issues with rc1 or has anyone encountered this one before?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So, I tracked the issue down to using new-relic for monitoring.

I'm not exactly sure why but commenting out the:

```
require('newrelic');
```

seems to do the trick.

I'm closing the question because it is apparently an external issue.

Newrelic doesn't accept issues on GitHub so I can't share a link for further info but I will update if and when this issue is solved.

EDIT:

Here's a support thread discussing the issue:
https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/issue-with-node-agent-1-11-2-and-sequelize/6951/6

Only solution seems to be to rollback for now.